# MembershipReboot with Identityserver 3 slow performance

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, identityserver3, membershipreboot

Running the MembersihpReboot application in completely separated systems, one is robust and the other kind of slow. Both systems running SQL2012 and VS2015, any suggestions would be helpful...

**The machine that having performance issue with this app, it takes over 20 seconds to return a token. runs in IIS express**

[image]

**The machine that runs smoothly, it only takes around 5 seconds to get the first token, and less than a second for the subsequent requests. runs in IIS in this case, tried IIS express and get the same results.**

[image]

**More details on this, it takes 12 seconds between the highlighted steps. This was based on the password hashing iteration count set to 10000**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have for the password hashing iteration count in the MembershipReboot config? this is the obvious reason that validating credentials would be slow.

Comment: Good point! I can see the one runs smoothly has this setting Config.PasswordHashingIterationCount = 10000; but the other machine has the same code base.....